# Remove rows based in a custom category order

Tags: r

```
# The order of my `class` variable is:
complete.cases <- c("Class_0_1","Class_1_3","Class_3_9", "Class_9_25","Class_25_50")   

# In my ds:
nest <- c(2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
TA <- c(2.3,5.9,8.7,11.8,14.9,11.9,8.8,5.7,2.4)
class <- c("Class_0_1","Class_1_3","Class_3_9","Class_3_9","Class_9_25","Class_1_3","Class_1_3","Class_1_3","Class_3_9")
my.ds <- data.frame(nest,TA,class)
my.ds
      nest   TA      class
1    2  2.3  Class_0_1
2    2  5.9  Class_1_3
3    2  8.7  Class_3_9
4    2 11.8  Class_3_9
5    2 14.9 Class_9_25
6    3 11.9  Class_1_3
7    3  8.8  Class_1_3
8    3  5.7  Class_1_3
9    3  2.4  Class_3_9

# About ds information:
nest <- c(2,3)
class_max <- c("Class_3_9","Class_1_3")
info.ds <- data.frame(nest,class_max)
```

Now I'd like to remove the rows based in the rule, `my.ds$class` up than `info.ds$class_max` by nest remove it, if not is OK.

My final dataframe: must to be:

```
# new.ds
#   nest   TA      class
# 1    2  2.3  Class_0_1
# 2    2  5.9  Class_1_3
# 3    2  8.7  Class_3_9
# 4    2 11.8  Class_3_9
# 5    3 11.9  Class_1_3
# 6    3  8.8  Class_1_3
# 7    3  5.7  Class_1_3
```

Please, any help with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert `class` to an *ordered factor* object and define a *custom order* for it with `ordered(x, levels)` or `factor(x, levels, ordered = TRUE)`.

```r
library(dplyr)

my.ds %>%
  mutate(class = ordered(class, levels = complete.cases)) %>%
  left_join(info.ds, by = 'nest') %>%
  filter(class <= class_max) %>%
  select(-class_max)

#   nest   TA     class
# 1    2  2.3 Class_0_1
# 2    2  5.9 Class_1_3
# 3    2  8.7 Class_3_9
# 4    2 11.8 Class_3_9
# 5    3 11.9 Class_1_3
# 6    3  8.8 Class_1_3
# 7    3  5.7 Class_1_3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option - join the two datasets and then do a group by `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
my.ds %>% 
  arrange(nest, factor(class, levels = complete.cases)) %>%
  left_join(info.ds, by = 'nest') %>%
   group_by(nest) %>% 
   slice(seq_len(last(which(class == class_max)))) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-class_max)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 3
   nest    TA class    
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
1     2   2.3 Class_0_1
2     2   5.9 Class_1_3
3     2   8.7 Class_3_9
4     2  11.8 Class_3_9
5     3  11.9 Class_1_3
6     3   8.8 Class_1_3
7     3   5.7 Class_1_3
```

Comment: @DarrenTsai it is assumed that the my.ds is already ordered (if not needs an `arrange` at the top, updated)